# How to parse milliseconds using Data.Time in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a formatted time strings from a log file of the form "08:14:59,012" and I would like to parse them as UTCTime (to be able to make some time difference and comparison operations).

I'm unable to find a way to parse the milliseconds. Here's what I have so far

```
import System.Locale (defaultTimeLocale)
import Data.Time (UTCTime)
import Data.Time.Format (readTime)

readHMS :: String -> UTCTime
readHMS = readTime defaultTimeLocale "%H:%M:%S"
-- ^^ How to parse milis? ""%H:%M:%S,%Q" doesn't work

test = readHMS "08:14:59,012"
```

Please suggest a way to parse milliseconds so that the test above contains them.

Comment: afaik the time library doesn't support parsing commas, so if your milliseconds have to be in that format I think you'll need to find another way to parse it, or simply convert the comma to a decimal point.

Comment: @unohoo: Actually, it does, but for picoseconds one _must_ use exactly twelve characters.

Comment: @Zeta: You're right. Thanks! I was able to work around it by appending 9 zero string and then parse it using "%H:%M:%S,%q"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though there isn't a format for milliseconds, you can use the format for picoseconds `%q` if you scale the milliseconds correctly. Luckily, this can be done by appending a fixed number of zeros, so that the resulting string has exactly 12 characters after your comma:

```
readHMS = readTime defaultTimeLocale "%H:%M:%S,%q"
                   --                         ^^^
                   --              vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
test    = readHMS $ "08:14:59,012" ++ replicate 9 '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I felt like appending 0's to have picosecond style didn't make much sense.
For the record, I'd do:

```
readHMS = readTime defaultTimeLocale "%H:%M:%S%q"
test    = readHMS "08:14:59,012" 
-- returns 1970-01-01 08:14:59.012 UTC
```

Because as stated [in the doc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.8.0.2/docs/Data-Time-Format.html#interface):

> > %Q
> >     decimal point and fraction of second, up to 12 second decimals, without trailing zeros. For a whole number of seconds, %Q omits the decimal point unless padding is specified.